# Receiving "Access to <mysitename.com> was denied HTTP Error 403" when trying to navigate to my phpmyadmin account

Tags: azure, phpmyadmin, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I created my app using the WordPress On App Service using the instructions found here: "https://github.com/Azure/wordpress-linux-appservice" -> Basically, a wordpress linux app service on azure with a MySQL Flexible server database. I migrated my site over to this azure app service using the all-in-one migration tool plugin.

The issue I am having is when I want to go to the <mysitename.com>/phpmyadmin, I get a login form and then when I try to log in using the DATABASE_username and DATABASE_password in my application settings (per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-wordpress#manage-the-mysql-flexible-server-username-or-password), it gives me the access denied error.

Edit in response to a comment - I am logged into the portal.azure.com, I navigate to my site. I have tried to then navigate to both mysitename.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin and also have tried the mysitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin. When I go to the first link, the login still shows up instead of automatically logging in. When I tried to do the second link it gives the error, "No route registered for "/phpmyadmin/".

Edit: I was wondering if my issue when accessing the PHPMYADMIN account, "403 - You don't have authorization to view this page" could be caused by the vnet integration configuration. I currently believe it could be a firewall or networking setting that is causing the issue, and that is the only setting that is currently on, but when I click on the vnet integration page, the values for the page (ex: vnet name, location, address space) are infinitely loading, so I can't tell if it could be the cause.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin is setup in the container at https:///home/phpmyadmin/ path.

https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/  (kudu) -Kudu by default uses single sign-on with your MS account.

https://yourappname.azurewebsites.net/
and then browse to phpAdmin interface at: https://yourappname>.**scm**.azurewebsites.net/phpMyAdmin/

Reference these docs for more info:
[wordpress_phpmyadmin.md](https://github.com/Azure/wordpress-linux-appservice/blob/main/WordPress/wordpress_phpmyadmin.md)
[Troubleshooting-FAQ-for-MySQL-in-app.html](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/09/08/Troubleshooting-FAQ-for-MySQL-in-app.html)

If you haven’t done this already post migration, restart the WebApp and then check.

Comment: Hi, I attempted to go to the https://yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpMyAdmin/ and it states "No route registered for '/phpmyadmin'" Do you know how to fix this? I followed the docs you mentioned but I do not have the buttons "MySql-in-app" or the button "Process Explorer"